# Margin between a title and the icons below it

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I try to modify a bootstrap template I downloaded. The existing setting for the title `What we do` is `<h2 class="title text-center sr-only">What we do</h2>`. But I want to show it, so I change this line to `<h2 class="title text-center">What we do</h2>`. The whole section code is as follows:

```
<section id="features" class="features section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <h2 class="title text-center">What we do</h2>
            <div class="item col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-center">
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>                
                </div><!--//icon-->
                <div class="content">
                    <h3 class="title">App Feature One</h3>
                    <p>Outline an app feature/benefit here. You can change the icon above to any of the 500+ <a href="http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/" target="_blank">FontAwesome icons</a> available. </p>  
                    <button class="modal-trigger btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#feature-modal-1">Find out more</button>
                </div><!--//content-->               
            </div><!--//item-->
            <div class="item col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-center">
            ...
            </div><!--//item-->
            <div class="item col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-center">
            ...
            </div><!--//item-->
        </div><!--//row-->
    </div><!--//container-->
</section><!--//features-->
```

And it looks as follows. The problem is that I feel **the title is too close to the icons below**.

[image]

However, this problem does not exist for the following existing code:

```
<section id="testimonials" class="testimonials section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h2 class="title text-center">What do people think?</h2>
            <div class="item col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                <div class="quote-box">
                    <i class="fa fa-quote-left"></i>
                    <blockquote class="quote">
                        <a href="#">@Delta</a> I love this #app. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. #Mobile
                    </blockquote><!--//quote-->
                </div><!--//quote-box-->
                <div class="people row">
                    <img class="img-rounded user-pic col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1" src="assets/images/people/people-1.png" alt="" />
                    <p class="details text-center pull-left">
                        <span class="name">Christine Heal</span>
                        <span class="title">Bristol, UK</span>
                    </p>                        
                </div><!--//people-->
            </div><!--//item-->
            <div class="item col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                <div class="quote-box">
                    ...
```

which shows:

[image]

Does anyone know how to modify the class style to give an appropriate space between the title and the icons below it?

PS: the `features` part in `base.less`:

```
.features {
    padding: 80px 0;
    .icon {
        position:relative;
        width: 90px;
        height: 90px;
        border: 3px solid @color;
        .border-radius(50%);
        display: table;
        margin: 0 auto;
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform ease-out 0.2s, background 0.3s;
        -moz-transition: -moz-transform ease-out 0.2s, background 0.3s;
        transition: transform ease-out 0.2s, background 0.3s; 

        &:hover {
            background: @color;
            color: #fff;                                    
            .fa {
                color: #fff;   
                .scale(0.93);             
            }
            .pe-icon {
                color: #fff;   
                .scale(0.93);  
            }
        }
        .fa {
            color: @color;
            font-size: 48px;
            display: table-cell;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;                        
        }
        .pe-icon {
            color: @color;
            font-size: 48px;
            display: table-cell;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;                        
        }
    }
    .content {
        padding: 30px;
        .title {
            color: @color;
            font-size: 18px;
            margin-top: 0;
        }
        p {
            font-weight: 300;
        }
    }
    .feature-row-last {
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
    .btn-link {
        color: @color;
        &:hover {
            color: darken(@color, 10%);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, you can see in the second example `<div class="item col-md-4 col-sm-4">`. These are built-in classes that may have pre-defined margins. Second, if you examine the page with Chrome, you can see very clearly what makes the space and how to add space wherever you want. Just right-click on any element and select **inspect element** (this exists in other browsers as well but Chrome's presentation is the best to my taste).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use padding in `<h2 class="title text-center">What we do</h2>` this line.

```
padding:10px 0px;
```

It will help you to give proper margin. change the css from firbug, so that you can see output.